# Equivalent for FILTER() formula in Libre Office

Tags: libreoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets

In a Google Spreadsheet, I create a report sheet by entering a formula like this in the top left cell.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:E, Sheet1!E2:E > 0)
```

This gives me all the rows in the Sheet1 from row 2 downwards where the value in column E is greater than 0.

What would be the equivalent in LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: Is that intended to be =FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!E2:E > 0) ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need automatic refresh, when the source table changed? If not, `Data->More Filters->Standard Filter` with the option `Copy results to` set to the desired sheet should do the trick.

Comment: No, With filter() function, you can then pass it to another function, for example to calculate standard deviation out of the resulting filter